# equality of derivative

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be deivatived in $x=x_0$.
Prove that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}=f'(x_0)$.
The problem is, that I think that I disproved it (but I know I have a mistake somewhere:
$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)+f(x_0)}{h}=
\frac{1}{2}(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h})=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x_0)-f'(x_0))=0$

But $f'(x_0)$ is not neccesserley equal to 0. Thanks.

Comment: you forgot to take the minus in the denominator.

Comment: Where exectly? Can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h} \neq f'(x_0)$ but $-f'(x_0)$. In the following all steps are correctly presented:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)+f(x_0)}{h} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-\big(f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)\big)}{h} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}\Big) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{-h}\Big) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(f'(x_0)+f'(x_0)\big)=f'(x_0)
\end{align*}